# Trouble using Implicit Ordered with PriorityQueue (Scala)

Tags: scala, priority-queue, implicits

I'm trying to create a data structure that has a `PriorityQueue` in it.  I've succeeded in making a non-generic version of it.  I can tell it works because it solves the A.I. problem I have.
Here is a snippet of it:

```
class ProntoPriorityQueue { //TODO make generic

implicit def orderedNode(node: Node): Ordered[Node] = new Ordered[Node] {
   def compare(other: Node) = node.compare(other)
}

val hashSet = new HashSet[Node]
val priorityQueue = new PriorityQueue[Node]()
...
```

I'm trying to make it generic, but if I use this version it stops solving the problem:

```
class PQ[T <% Ordered[T]] {
//[T]()(implicit val ord: T => Ordered[T]) {
//[T]()(implicit val ord: Ordering[T] {

val hashSet = new HashSet[T]
val priorityQueue = new PriorityQueue[T]
...
```

I've also tried what's commented out instead of using `[T <% Ordered[T]]`

Here is the code that calls `PQ`:

```
//the following def is commented out while using ProntoPriorityQueue
implicit def orderedNode(node: Node): Ordered[Node] = new Ordered[Node] {
     def compare(other: Node) = node.compare(other)
} //I've also tried making this return an Ordering[Node]

val frontier = new PQ[Node] //new ProntoPriorityQueue
//have also tried (not together): 
val frontier = new PQ[Node]()(orderedNode)
```

I've also tried moving the implicit def into the `Node` object (and importing it), but essentially the same problem.

What am I doing wrong in the generic version?  Where should I put the implicit?

---

**Solution**
The problem was not with my implicit definition.  The problem was the implicit ordering was being picked up by a `Set` that was automatically generating in a `for(...) yield(...)` statement.  This caused a problem where the yielded set only contained one state.

Answer (score 1):

What's wrong with simply defining an `Ordering` on your `Node` (`Ordering[Node]`) and using the already-generic Scala `PriorityQueue`?

As general rule, it's better to work with `Ordering[T]` than `T <: Ordered[T]` or `T <% Ordered[T]`. Conceptually, `Ordered[T]` is an intrinsic (inherited or implemented) property of the type itself. Notably, a type can have only one intrinsic ordering relationship defined this way. `Ordering[T]` is an external specification of the ordering relationship. There can any be any number of different `Ordering[T]`.

Also, if you're not already aware, you should know that the difference between `T <: U` and `T <% U` is that while the former includes only nominal subtype relations (actual inheritance), the latter also includes the application of implicit conversions that yield a value conforming to the type bound.

So if you want to use `Node <% Ordered[Node]` and you don't have a `compare` method defined in the class, an implicit conversion will be applied *every time a comparison needs to be made*. Additionally, if your type *has* its own `compare`, the implicit conversion will never be applied and you'll be stuck with that "built-in" ordering.

**Addendum**

I'll give a few examples based on a class, call it `CIString` that simply encapsulates a `String` and implements ordering as case-invariant.

```
/* Here's how it would be with direct implementation of `Ordered` */

class   CIString1(val s: String)
extends Ordered[CIString1]
{
  private val lowerS = s.toLowerCase

  def compare(other: CIString1) = lowerS.compareTo(other.lowerS)
}

/* An uninteresting, empty ordered set of CIString1
    (fails without the `extends` clause) */
val os1 = TreeSet[CIString1]()


/* Here's how it would look with ordering external to `CIString2`
    using an implicit conversion to `Ordered` */

class CIString2(val s: String) {
  val lowerS = s.toLowerCase
}

class CIString2O(ciS: CIString2)
extends Ordered[CIString2]
{
  def compare(other: CIString2) = ciS.lowerS.compareTo(other.lowerS)
}

implicit def cis2ciso(ciS: CIString2) = new CIString2O(ciS)

/* An uninteresting, empty ordered set of CIString2
    (fails without the implicit conversion) */
val os2 = TreeSet[CIString2]()


/* Here's how it would look with ordering external to `CIString3`
    using an `Ordering` */

class CIString3(val s: String) {
  val lowerS = s.toLowerCase
}

/* The implicit object could be replaced by
    a class and an implicit val of that class */
implicit
object  CIString3Ordering
extends Ordering[CIString3]
{
  def compare(a: CIString3, b: CIString3): Int = a.lowerS.compareTo(b.lowerS)
}

/* An uninteresting, empty ordered set of CIString3
    (fails without the implicit object) */
val os3 = TreeSet[CIString3]()
```

Comment: I've tried extending `Ordering[Node]` on my Node.  I've implemented both a `compare(other: Node)` and `compare(some: Node, other: Node)`

This caused a bunch of problems in other method calls that involve `Node`

Here are some of them: 
- diverging implicit expansion for type 
  scala.collection.generic.CanBuildFrom[main.Moves.ValueSet,Option[main.Node],That] starting with method 
  newCanBuildFrom in object SortedSet
 - not enough arguments for method map: (implicit bf: 
  scala.collection.generic.CanBuildFrom[main.Moves.ValueSet,Option[main.Node],That])That. Unspecified value 
  parameter bf

Comment: @Tombstone: You don't make your `Node` class extend `Ordering[Node]`, you define a class that extends `Ordering[Node]` that defines the ordering relationship on `Node` by defining the method `compare`.

Comment: I've made a new class that extends Ordering[Node] and it works.  Thank you.  I still have a question regarding implicits.  How come my previous implicits didn't work?

      `implicit def nodeOrderer: Ordering[Node] = new Ordering[Node]{
       def compare(some: Node, other: Node) = some.compare(other)
      }`
      `implicit val ordN: Ordering[Node] = new Ordering[Node] {
       def compare(some: Node, other: Node) = some.compare(other)
      }`

Comment: @Tombstone: You have to combine properly typed (they were) in-scope (they would have been, were they not commented out) implicit conversions _with_ the `<%` type bound, not instead of it.

Comment: Thanks for your patients helping me.  Sadly I still haven't figured it out.  Could you please give me how you would define the class, a call to the constructor, and the implicit def to use?

Comment: @Tombstone: Did the examples help?

Comment: Yes the examples help.  Thank you.  I've come to the conclusion through testing and debugging that whenever I define an `Ordering` or `Ordered` for Node implicitly, it screws up the algorithm.  

After some investigation, I found that it likely had to do with a `for(...) yield (...)` call, because it was returning a `SortedSet[Node]` with just one item.  After making the loop use a `MutableList`, the implicit works -but produces a higher cost solution.  That's another mystery I'll have to figure out.

Answer (score 0):

Well, one possible problem is that your `Ordered[Node]` *is not* a `Node`:

```
implicit def orderedNode(node: Node): Ordered[Node] = new Ordered[Node] {
  def compare(other: Node) = node.compare(other)
}
```

I'd try with an `Ordering[Node]` instead, which you say you tried but there isn't much more information about. `PQ` would be declared as `PQ[T : Ordering]`.

Comment: I've changed `PQ` definition to:
`class PQ[T : Ordering] {...`
and changed my implicit def to:
`implicit def orderedNode: Ordering[Node] = new Ordering[Node] {
         def compare(some: Node, other: Node) = some.compare(other)
      }` 
and it still doesn't work

Comment: @Tombstone Well, there's not enough information. All you are giving us is that an algorithm that depends on it isn't working any longer -- which I suspect to be a bug in the algorithm. In the absence of a "it does X when I do Y, and it should do Z instead", all we can do is guesswork.

Comment: There could be problem in the algorithm, but I doubt there is for a few reasons: 1.) It's based on my graph search algorithm that has worked for other data structures for the explored set (LIFO, FIFO) and even w/o an explored set 2.) The biggest difference is changing from a stack||queue to a priority queue  3.) I had it working using a data structure that was non-generic (and now have a non-generic, non-implicit version working).  To put all relevant information of the algorithm would take hundreds of lines.  https://www.dropbox.com/s/lw63j1vq8k94mu4/tombstone%20src.zip